# Merchant Key Missing error

Tags: spring-mvc, payu

Am new to the spring mvc. am redirecting to payu website  below is my controller method

```
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:https://test.payu.in/_payment",model);
```

all parameters sending through model object

```
 model.put("amount", amount);
          model.put("productinfo",productInfo);
          model.put("firstname",fname);
          model.put("email", email);
          model.put("phone","1234541589");
          model.put("surl",successUrl);
          model.put("furl",failureUrl);
          model.put("udf1",udf1);
          model.put("udf2",udf2);
          model.put("txnid",txnid.toString());
          model.put("key", "gtKFFx");
         model.put("hash", hash);
```

all parameters having values.

Comment: getting same error